# Concat 2 arrays but one of them contains subarray

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have 2 arrays. The first one is simple:

[image]

The second one contains sub-arrays:

[image]

and every element of the sub-arrays should be concated to the first one so they can form one array of same elements.

Here is sandbox:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-dust-kpg5l?file=/src/App.js

Arrays are data1 and data2. Final data is how it should look like. I tried several loops to form it but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: you can spread into the concat call `arr1.concat(...arr2)`. But for such a specific question don't link to an outside codebase, instead provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

[`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to the rescue:

```
const newArr = [...data1, ...data2.flatMap((el) => el)];
```